# What is a t-test and how is it used in relation to animal physiology?

Tags: t-test

How do you find the confidence level and P value in a t-test?
For example, how would you use these variables to compare Daphnia heart rates and their circulatory activity?

Comment: Is that a homework question? If so, please add a `self-study` tag and read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: No. I genuinely want to learn about the subject because I would like to start experimenting in a lab setting.

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia entry on the t-test? It is a fairly extensive description. Are there specific things you don't understand about the t-test, or the concepts of confidence level and p-value in particular?

Comment: I don't understand its very purpose and how the confidence level and p-value are used in the test.

Comment: OK. It would help if you gave us more information, more details of what you are working on. Because as of now it is hard to recommend anything particular.

Comment: For example, how would it be used for Daphnia heart rate results?

Comment: Please bear in mind that not all of us are experts in animal psychology. You should formulate the question in a relevant amount of detail so that anyone could understand what you might be after. I suggest you work on the question a bit more and update it instead of adding comments.

Comment: Can you edit it for me? I'm not quite sure what changes I need to make since I'm a new member here.

Comment: Sorry, but it is you who knows what you are doing. I cannot formulate the question for you. You could start by telling a story what you are investigating, what data you have and what hypotheses could be of interest. Then we could help you work on the statistical details of implementing your idea. But you have to come up with a relatively clear idea first.

Answer (score 5):

This is the key passage in the [Wikipedia entry for the t test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test):

> It can be used to determine if two sets of data are significantly different from each other.

As @whuber notes, this is actually wrong in a way that may seem like nitpicking: a t test actually assesses whether the *means* of two data sets differ significantly.

For instance, you might have two samples of [Daphnia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphnia), which you collected from two different puddles. You have collected a heart rate from each individual. You can then use a t test to test whether the average heart rates differ significantly between the two samples (e.g., because of pollution, nutrients or something else).

To expand on the difference between "testing whether two sets of data are significantly different from each other" and "testing whether two sets differ significantly *on their means*", assume that one set of heart rates is normally distributed around a mean of 100 with a standard deviation of 1, while the other is normally distributed around 100 with a standard deviation of 10. The t test will tell you truthfully that the means do not differ significantly ... although the variances are *quite* different. In R:

```
set.seed(1)
foo <- cbind(rnorm(30, 100, 10), rnorm(30, 100, 1))
plot(jitter(rep(1, 30), 5), foo[, 1], pch=19, xlim=c(.5,2.5), 
     xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="")
points(jitter(rep(2, 30), 5), foo[, 2], pch=19)
t.test(foo[, 1], foo[, 2])

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  foo[, 1] and foo[, 2]
t = 0.4085, df = 29.43, p-value = 0.6858
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.769478  4.153092
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 100.8246  100.1328
```

[image: t]

This may illustrate why people are asking for more information. It's really hard to answer a statistical question without knowing what the question is.

Comment: Now I see the source of so much confusion in questions on this site! So many people seem to think that a t-test determines whether entire "sets of data" are "significantly different" in some vague, holistic sense, even though it only compares their *means.*

Comment: @whuber: good point. Let me edit before I become a party to perpetuating misinformation...

Comment: Wikipedia isn't very reliable. Do you have any other sources of information? (I appreciate your answer by the way!)

Comment: Yes: our site discusses t-tests in hundreds of posts, providing data, examples, and extensive discussion.  Why don't you look at [a few of them](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-test)?

Comment: Can you please provide some links?

Comment: Click on the [tag:t-test] tag to get all questions tagged `t-test`. Or look into almost any statistics textbook, e.g. [here](http://www.statsoft.com/Textbook/Basic-Statistics).